# Accessing labels and combo boxes from another form C#

Tags: c#

I'm being asked to access labels, text boxes, and combo boxes from another form. 
From the input form to the main form using this:

```
frmInput input = new frmInput();
```

This ^^ is in my main form. 
When i go to use "intelesense" it doesn't show any of the labels or anything that i need. 
Suggestions?

Comment: Tell the one you asked to do so that you need business requirements and you will implement in a way that you will satisfy their business requirements, you will be able to do so without exposing the form's controls to another form...

Comment: Please don't go down the road of your UI elements being business objects.  Those following you will appreciate it.

Comment: I asked to do this because in the code i that was given to me by my teacher it says that i just declare the frminput form as shown and i'm just able to access them. And because I can't I'm just a little lost is all. ^-^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because by default GUI elements are defined with private access. If you want to expose them then define your own properties for these elements. You also needs to pass the reference to your main form to the input form... However not recommended.

Instead you can use Events to communicate data between form and keep the rendering to the control's parent form.

Comment: +1 on not recommended. But there's no need to define them yourself: you can set the access through the designer. On the Properties window by changing the "Modifiers" property. But let's pretend I never said that, ok?

Comment: +1 for pretending... :P............ and by the way that why I mentioned by default.. With to define properties for them I meant properties to set or get the required properties for that control.. i.e. lable1.Text;

Comment: Thanks for that little tip. Ironically, i over looked the fact that i was suppose to change the Modifier to public. >>' I would have exspected something a little harder but eh. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That controls can be declared private or protected and that's why you can't access them. However you can either make them public or access by name:

```
input.Controls["someButtonName"]
```